# Difficulty determining font showing a "Z" like a "Q" creatively on WorldBank.org

Tags: font-identification

Word in question is "Marginalized" (from http://www.worldbank.org/en/topic/socialprotection and searching through [news/all/](http://www.worldbank.org/en/news/all)) here attached:

[image: "Z" shown as "Q"]

Font is showing a "Z" like a "Q" creatively on WorldBank.org, after checking "Andes" from multiple font repositories and entering each of the letters, nothing shows like WorldBank.org's version.

Discrepancy: [WhatTheFont (WTF)](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/result) said [Corporative](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/latinotype/corporative) ([Alt Hair](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/latinotype/corporative/alt-hair)) is the correct answer, but the Chrome Inspector/Inspect Elements Text `Filter` Field does not show "Corporative" (see the blue highlight) which is confusing (I can not tell if that is an error or the named "font family" extends somehow otherwise to other font names).

(Led by [Social Protection](http://www.worldbank.org/en/topic/socialprotection), the page in question, advertising, among others, http://www.worldbank.org/en/news/press-release/2011/09/23/eurozone-crisis-clouds-recovery-emerging-europe-central-asia [you need to search for that through the [/socialprotection/](http://www.worldbank.org/en/topic/socialprotection) link to read the lettering, it changes font for the actual article], for another example, I read the letter multiple times and still could not read.

I tried to save an archive.org copy for evidence and because of the fancy styling it is painful (or so far impossible, another task to learn another code library) to do a "faithful archive" of the lettering.)

Comment: Hi OP, could you please [edit] your question to clean up the layout a bit, right now it's an unreadable mess of links. [Here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links) you can find help on formatting links. Thanks!

Comment: Organized the messier links[(*)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/revisions/117031/2), so looks healthier at least. Still thinking using full URL's for the source code of the problem may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **the "stylistic alternate" variant of Andes font family**.

Debugging the site, out of many fonts used, there are 2 fonts that looks like the object of this question:

> [image: font 1] [image: font 2]

Aside of the thickness/weight, Andes has 2 variants that affect the lowercase 'aegyz':

> [image: Andes normal]
>
> <sup>Andes "normal" variant</sup>
>
> [image]
>
> <sup>Andes "stylistic alternate" variant</sup>

The one you're looking for is the stylistic alternate variant of Andes font family. (you can see the variant on [myFonts](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/latinotype/andes/#index))

---

<sup>Disclaimer: not affiliated to the site. I only found the site that can easily demonstrate the variant compared to other font sites. Suggestion to the more official font sites is open.</sup>

Comment: TY, definitely debugging, I did not know about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font#Character_variants. With https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304718/fontspec-doesnt-find-stylistic-variants-in-gentium-basic so far I know I am not alone totally missing that. Took me literally 20 minutes (almost sounded stupid by beginning to write questioning your logic) to realize I had to click the "FF" (sp?) button for settings. Thank you.

Comment: "ʐ" is actually an IPA letter https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CA%90, you gave me some of the keywords to take a step deeper into the jargon, and ask if that was just style.